# Display node's details instead of ID with relation module

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

**I have create Two node ‘Partners’ & ‘Project form’.**

**I used relation module & create directional relation between two nodes.**

**Partner’s node have following fields:**
 [image]

**I have to select multiple partners in Project form, so I added relation widget into project form for create relation with partner’s node. Currently that field’s display partners node id as per below screenshot:**

[image]

**Instead of that I want to display partner’s details like (partner name-dept-country-city) & also allow to search using same string as per below screen-shot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the reference fields there will be an option to display view as a reference option. You need to create a view and attach it there.

Comment: refrence field are availabe with 'relation select' not with 'relation add' and how can we attach concated string using views.